# IF statement within WHILE not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am working on a basic messaging system. This is to get all the messages and to make the row of the table that has an unread message Green. In the table, there is a column called 'msgread'. this is set to '0' by default. Therefore it should make any row with the msgread = 0 -> green. this is only working for the first row of the table with the code i have - i verified that it is always getting a 0 value, however it only works the first time through in the while statement ..

```
require('./connect.php');

$getmessages = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toperson = '" . $userid . "'";

echo $getmessages;

$messages = mysql_query($getmessages);

if(mysql_num_rows($messages) != 0) {

    $table = "<table><tr><th>From</th><th>Subject</th><th>Message</th></tr>";

    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($messages)) {

        if(strlen($results[message]) < 30){
            $message = $results[message];
        }
        else {
            $message = substr($results[message], 0 ,30) . "...";
        }

        if($results[msgread] == 0){

            $table .= "<tr style='background:#9CFFB6'>";
            $table .= "<td>" . $results[from] . "</td><td>" . $results[subject] . "</td><td><a href='viewmessage.php?id=" . $results[message_id] ."'>" . $message . "</a></td></tr>";
        }
        else {
            $table .= "<tr>";
            $table .= "<td>" . $results[from] . "</td><td>" . $results[subject] . "</td><td><a href='viewmessage.php?id=" . $results[message_id] ."'>" . $message . "</a></td></tr>";

        }
    }
    echo $table ."</table>";
}
else {
    echo "No Messages Found";   
}
```

There's all the code, including grabbing the info from  the database. Thanks.

Comment: its probably interpreting $results[message] - the message part, as a definition, which would be NULL if not defined

Comment: @BarryChapman i changed everything to $results['messages'] ... (added quotes) .. still no luck

Comment: Use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()`

Comment: @BarryChapman did that (what's the difference by the way?) .. still only highlighting the first time, then subsequent times it doesn't ..

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc will parse like an associative array instead of a numerically indexed array

Comment: @BarryChapman oh ok, thanks. Still trying to get it to work, very perplexed as to why a simple if statement is not being executed as expected..

Comment: because the conditions of the if arent met

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` will ONLY return a associative array while `mysql_fetch_array()` will return both (associative and numerical). If the numerical array is not needed `mysql_fetch_assoc` should be used to save some ressources.

Comment: OK, i found the following: .. i echoed $result['msgread']  and it only echoed a 0 one time, the second time it echoed nothing .. any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the data in your table?

Answer (score 5):

```
if(strlen($results[message]) < 30){
```

the message probably should be quoted:

```
if(strlen($results['message']) < 30){
```

There are quite a few other similar issues

Answer (score 1):

i tested your code an the only mistake i found was the lack of quoatation marks in the indices array $results. You are using this `$result[message_id]` when the most appropriate would be `$result['message_id']`. The rest works as expected, the records with msgread equal to 0 stayed with the green line.

Comment: thanks, now i'm very perplexed, because even after adding quotes, the green background only occurs the first time, the consequent messages don't work :(

Comment: How many reviews are registered in the database? Who's with msgread equal to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks a little nasty and is not easy to read.

- You should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.
- Always end style with a ;
- use quotation on associative array
- more logic choice of var names
- where does `$userid` come from? is the content safe?

Here is quickly cleaned version of your code :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE toperson = '" . $userid . "'";

if($results = mysqli_query($query)) {

    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) != 0) {

        $table = "<table><tr><th>From</th><th>Subject</th><th>Message</th></tr>";

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {

            if(strlen($data['message']) > 30){
                $data['message'] = substr($data['message'], 0 ,30) . "...";
            }

            $table .= "<tr";

            if($data['msgread'] == 0){
                $table .= " style='background:#9CFFB6;'";
            }

            $table .= ">";

            $table .= "<td>" . $data['from'] . "</td><td>" . $data['subject'] . "</td><td><a href='viewmessage.php?id=" . $data['message_id'] ."'>" . $data['message'] . "</a></td></tr>";

        }

        echo $table ."</table>";

    } else {

        echo "No Messages Found";   

    }  
}
```

Comment: Please try to keep formatting suggestions and general tips (when not attempting to answer the question) as edits to the question or comments rather than in an answer..

Comment: @asifrc It might be the reason for his problem. I have seen the lack of quotation marks on associative arrays and also the lack of `;` in styles giving unpredictable behavior.